# Why when using SSL and Port 443 only am I getting a Socket Refused Error on Port 80?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

I have a ASP.NET MVC site set up in `IIS7` on `Win2K8` with a single `SSL` binding on Port 443. The team in charge of the server only has port 443 open for security reasons, but this shouldn't be any issue because that's the only binding I have and I'm not making any regular `HTTP` calls on port 80.

When I call my site, my main login page (using `forms authentication`) comes up in the browser (over `HTTPS`) which looks fine. However, as soon as I try to login I get the following error:

```
[SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.x.123.123:80]
```

Ok that is the correct IP assigned to the site, but I'm not making any calls on port 80. Why would I get this error if all I need is a `SSL` binding on port 443? Am I required to have port 80 open as well? I'm not making any calls internally that use port 80, unless MVC is doing something I'm unaware of that requires port 80.

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When digging into the code it turns out that our service turned around and made additional `REST` calls to other parts of the same service using a `HTTP` url, thus causing the error.

Since I configured `IIS` to only allow `SSL` traffic and I had internal calls to a `HTTP` URL the error was generated. The root cause was that I forgot we were making RESTful calls within the code and those URLs had to be updated to their respective `HTTPS` counterpart.